# Setting dynamic page titles in Durandal 2.1.0

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal, durandal-2.0

I use an observable inside the `updateDocumentTitle` function that gets a new value after completing an ajax request. But I noticed that the `updateDocumentTitle` function doesn't fire again after the observable changes its value.

```
userShell.prototype.router.updateDocumentTitle = function(instance, instruction) {
  document.title = instance.userArr().name();
};
```

I tried wrapping the contents of `updateDocumentTitle` inside a computed observable, but for some reason when I navigate between user pages that are under the same shell (users/100 to users/105), the computed observable gets called as many times as I have navigated between pages without refreshing.

Are there any other successful ways of setting a dynamic document title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a competition between *when* `updateDocumentTitle()` fires and when your AJAX request completes successfully.

Where does your AJAX call get made, in which Durandal handler for the viewModel?  You have `activate`, `attached`, and `compositionComplete` handlers to choose from.

**[EDIT]**

You will need to abandon `updateDocumentTitle()` in this case.  Simply create an observable in your viewModel.  Update that observable from the `activate` handler *upon successful completion of your AJAX call*. Make sure you bind to that observable in your view.  We actually do that ourselves for the same reasons you would need to.

For robustness, make sure you provide a default title in the event your AJAX call fails.

Comment: The ajax call is inside the shell's `activate` function. Wherever I put it, the response will come after the `updateDocumentTitle` has fired.

Comment: I have the same ajax that runs on page init and on `:id` change. On init, it finishes before `compositionComplete`, so Durandal overwrites the document title after it finishes the composition. On `:id` change, I used your solution and it worked. Then while I was trying to figure out how to make it work on page init, I noticed that if I leave `updateDocumentTitle()` blank, Durandal doesn't try to change the title after composition. Thanks for the help!